# String Search Function

Tags: pandas

So this works:

```
idocs[idocs['Message'].str.contains('No sold-to found')]
```

But this doesn't:

```
def msg_logic(msg):
    if msg.str.contains('No sold-to found'):
       return 'No Sold-to'
    else:
       return 'Other'

idocs['Category'] = idocs.apply(lambda x: msg_logic(x['Message']),axis=1)
print(idocs['Category'].unique())    
idocs.head()
```

Comment: No need for self depreciation my man, can you post 5-10 rows of your input and output data?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". It's probably so much easier to spot the error with the stacktrace

Comment: AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index nan')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def msg_logic(msg):
    if 'No sold-to found' in msg:
       return 'No Sold-to'
    else:
       return 'Other'

idocs['Category'] = idocs.apply(lambda x: msg_logic(x['Message']),axis=1)
print(idocs['Category'].unique())    
idocs.head()
```

Your code does not run because `msg` in the function is a string no a dataframe.

or

```
idocs['Category'] = idocs['Message'].apply(lambda x: "No Sold-to" if "No sold-to found" in x else "Other")
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend `np.where`

```
idocs['Category'] = (np.where(idocs['Message'].str.contains('No sold-to found'),
                             'No Sold-to',
                             'Other'))
```

For multiple conditions, use `np.select`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `np.select`. Neat! Voting up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
idocs['Category'] = idocs['Message'].str.contains('No sold-to found')
idocs['Category'] = idocs['Category'].apply(lambda x: 'No Sold-to' if x else 'Other')
```

Comment: what if instead of 'Other' I have multiple conditions?

Comment: Then please give some example data in your question for that scenario. And we will see.

Comment: if multiple conditions, can definitely use if, elif,...else to do whatever you want